# Include all lines in between the first and last occurrence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a txt file which has text in this manner:

```
    [2018-07-11 20:57:08] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "hello"
    [2018-07-11 20:57:19] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "hi! how is it going?"
    [2018-07-11 20:57:19] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "It's going pretty good. 
     How about you?"
    [2018-07-11 14:05:20] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): I've been doing good too!

    Thank you.
    [2018-07-12 14:05:20] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello!"
    How is your day going today?
    [2018-07-12 14:05:34] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "Great! Can't complain"
    [2018-07-12 14:05:34] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Okay. 
    That's good"
```

Now, I want all the lines from the first occurrence of [2018-07-11] to the last, and all the line in between. 
Currently, I am just finding all the lines that start with [2018-07-11.. and displaying them, but if you notice, there are few lines which are in between them too which are getting lost.

```
for line in file:
    if b in line: #b = system input of date
       x = x + "//" + line[11:]
    else:
       x=x
```

Sample output would be something like:
For the date 2018-11-17:

```
20:57:08] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "hello"
20:57:19] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "hi! how is it going?"
20:57:19] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "It's going pretty good. 
How about you?"
14:05:20] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): I've been doing good too!
Thank you.
```

for the date: 2018-07-12:

```
14:05:20] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello!"
How is your day going today?
14:05:34] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "Great! Can't complain"
14:05:34] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Okay. 
That's good"
```

Any idea on how I would be able to get the lines in between too? Since it all depends on dates- there is no way an occurrence of a that can happen later on in the text.

Comment: Simply read the date (7-11) and figure out what the next date should be (if this can be predicted, if not simply check when you see data in a date format that is different than the previous.) This is less about figuring out when to keep reading the lines and rather when to stop reading the lines and close off that date

Comment: Can you post a sample output? Based on the explanation its not clear.

Comment: @madmatrix He's basically trying to get all lines transcribed on a given date but they are not all tagged with the date, so simply checking for the date at the beginning of the string doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Hello! I have added the sample output. Hope it helps:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to parse the lines. I made a function `find_lines_by_date()` where you can supply the date string and it will return a list of lines with this date:

```
data = """
    [2018-07-11 20:57:08] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "hello"
    [2018-07-11 20:57:19] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "hi! how is it going?"
    [2018-07-11 20:57:19] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "It's going pretty good.
     How about you?"
    [2018-07-11 14:05:20] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): I've been doing good too!

    Thank you.
    [2018-07-12 14:05:20] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello!"
    How is your day going today?
    [2018-07-12 14:05:34] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "Great! Can't complain"
    [2018-07-12 14:05:34] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Okay.
    That's good"
"""

import re
import pprint

def find_lines_by_date(date='2018-07-11'):
    rv = []
    groups = re.findall(r'(\[(.*?)\s+.*?\][^\[]+)', data)
    for g in groups:
        if g[-1] == date:
            rv.append(g[0].strip())
    return rv


pprint.pprint(find_lines_by_date(date='2018-07-12'))
```

This will print:

```
['[2018-07-12 14:05:20] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello!"\n'
 '    How is your day going today?',
 '[2018-07-12 14:05:34] USER INPUT (xvp_dev-0): "Great! Can\'t complain"',
 '[2018-07-12 14:05:34] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Okay.\n    That\'s good"']
```

EDIT:

The regexp `(\[(.*?)\s+.*?\][^\[]+)` will match the string for all two-valued groups (first value in the group contains all the line for return value, second value in the group is the date for comparison).

I made a [simple example on external site](https://regex101.com/r/xrNZgf/1) with detailed explication:

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to parse the data, and then `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re
dates = re.findall('\[.*?\]', content)
content = [re.findall('(?<=:)[\w\W]+', i) for i in re.sub('\[.*?\]', '*', content).split('*')]
final_content = [re.sub('\n+|\s{2,}', '', ''.join(i)) for i in content if i]
d = list(zip(dates, final_content))
new_d= [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:re.findall('\d+\-\d+\-\d+', x[0])[0]), key=lambda x:re.findall('\d+\-\d+\-\d+', x[0])[0])]
final_result = {a:[c for _, c in b] for a, b in new_d}
```

Output:

```
{'2018-07-12': [' "Hello!"How is your day going today?', 
                ' "Great! Can\'t complain"', 
                ' "Okay.That\'s good"'], 
 '2018-07-11': [' "hello"', 
                ' "hi! how is it going?"', 
                ' "It\'s going pretty good.How about you?"', 
                " I've been doing good too!Thank you."]}
```

Now, all the responses found for each date are contained in a list as a value in a dictionary with the date itself as the key.